# Probablity Problem followed

Tags: probability, statistics

A study shows 10% of all businessmen who wear ties wear them so tight that the ties actually reduce blood flow to the brain. At a board meeting of 25 businessmen, all of whom wear ties.
What is the probability that more than 3 ties are too tight? What about for probability that no tie is too tight?

For at least one, I got 0.928.

Comment: In the second to last sentence, you are missing an essential word between "than" and "ties". You are correct about the answer to the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just simple use of [Binomial distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Case $1$: If *more than one person* wears a tight tie, the probability is: $$P_1 = 1- P_{\text {No person wears a tight tie}} - P_{\text {One person wears a tight tie}}-P_{\text {Two wear a tight tie}} - P_{\text {Three wear a tight tie}} $$ $$=1-\sum_{i=0}^{3} (\binom {25}{i}(0.9)^{25-i}(0.1)^i) $$ $$=1- (\binom {25}{0}(0.9)^{25}(0.1)^{0})-(\binom {25}{1}(0.9)^{24}(0.1)^1)- (\binom {25}{2}(0.9)^{23}(0.1)^2)-(\binom {25}{3}(0.9)^{22}(0.1)^3)$$

We have considered wearing a tight tie as a success, the probability of which equals $0.1$.

Case $2$: If *no one* wears a tight tie, the probability is: $$P_2 = (0.9)^{25}$$

You are right in calculating the probability of *at least one person* wears a tight tie. Hope it helps.

Comment: Rohan, thank you for the response. Turns out I missed a word or two in the first part. Can you kindly check it again? Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Just wondering, what that (25 0) thing on the front it. I am trying to know how to calculate that.

Comment: @James It is called a [combination](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).